# How can I isolate the username of an email address using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, string, ecmascript-6

I have an email list, but in order to assign the username to a new variable, I need to delete all the characters after the @ symbol. 
Is there a way to do this via regex in javascript?

```
var input = "john@email.com" //this is my input
var result = "john" //this is what I need after stripping all characters after the @ symbol

function strip(input){
this.result =  //how can I strip everything after the @ ??
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `split()` the string by `@` and get the first element.

```js
var input = "john@email.com";
let res =input.split('@')[0]
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

If not validation needs to be done on the email string, then you could use

```js
function strip(input){
        var pattern = /(.*?)@.*?/
        var output = input.match(pattern);
        var result =  output && output[1] ? output[1] : ""   //how can I strip everything after the @ ??
        console.log("Input--> " + input + "  Output --> " + result);
    }
    
    strip("john@email.com");
    strip("@email.com");
    strip("email.com");
    strip("john@");
```

But you would still end up with "John" as a result if the input email string is "John@"

Comment: Change regex to `/(.*?)@.*\..*?/` to prevent false positive from `john@`. This is valid as all email address have at least a single `.` in the domain part unless requiring support for local domain only address.